# "It feels so good" vs. "I feel so good" vs. "It makes me feel so good"

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-choice

What are the differences between following sentences, in terms of meaning?

> It feels (so) good
>
> I feel (so) good
>
> It makes me feel (so) good

---

For me it sounds like we need a driver/thing to say "it feels so good".  For example, when we return to our parents' house after a long journey in the Himalayas, we can say "It feels so good to be home again."  But we can say "I feel good" with or without a reason.  We can say "Today is a beautiful day and I feel so good".  Because a beautiful day is probably nice, but not too surprising, even in the UK:)  But how about when we hear a song that makes us happy, or when we read an impressive novel, or stay at home to relax?

And I don't know how to say this, but when we say "it feels so good", does it have double *entendres*?

Comment: minor point - it would be *in* the Himalayas, even though at no point did you go below the ground. [I have no real idea why that is, but it is] For some reason smarter people than me may be able to explain, you can be 'on a mountain' but you are 'in the mountain range'

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for your advice.after I asked the question, I became confused actually but because I do not know which preposition go with the best for the himalayas, I just left it out in the way I had written at first.But I think I should use "to" instead of "on" to stress the journey

Comment: 'in, on & to' would actually be a whole question in itself, tbh. I just thought it worth mentioning in passing.

Comment: 'to' would imply you went there & came back again, it gives no further information. 'in' gives the impression you did some driving around there, some sightseeing, holidaying etc, rather than just went as far as the signpost saying 'welcome to the Himalayas' then came home again ;)

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to take an innocuous example - taking a shower…

> Taking a shower feels so good

I enjoy simply the feeling of the water, the heat [or coolness, depending on the current weather]

> I feel so good, when I'm taking a shower

I get a feeling of satisfaction from doing something healthy & cleansing.

> It makes me feel so good, that I want to take more showers.

…hmm… maybe my choice of innocuous subject wasn't quite so innocuous - there are *always* going to be double-entendre opportunities in any form of 'enjoyment'.

Comment: Thank you.I gave a lot of situation as an example because I wanted to make my question more general than specific.But explaning only one example is useful too..So can we say they all have similar meaning.

Comment: There is a similarity, but depending on whether it's eating an apple, taking a shower, or being paid attention by someone you really would like to see more [literally] of, the 'frisson' & double… even single-… entendre can change. Frankly, sexual jokes are a millimetre away at any time, no matter how innocent the actual intent - unless you really are in a conversation about how good it felt to be home again. Context is all-important in this one.

Answer (score 2):

These are all quite similar but have different nuances of meaning:

"**It feels (so) good**" is describing ***it.***

"**I feel (so) good**" is describing ***me.***

"**It makes me feel (so) good**" is indicating causation.

So if I want to tell someone about ***it*** I might use the first.
If I want to tell someone about ***me*** I might use the second.
And if I want to tell someone about what ***it does to me***, I'd use the third.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "It feels so good," you're using a pronoun: It. And pronouns need antecedents -- something that they're pronouning *for*. (Sometimes you can get away with "he" or "she," especially in fiction, because they are so commonly used for "a man"/"a woman.") So yes, whenever you have a "It feels so good" or "It makes me feel so good," you need to have some explanation/context for what "it" is. E.g., if you slip into a hot bath, you can sigh, "It feels so good," and anyone around you will intuit that the context means "it" refers to the bath.

When the context is lacking, then the "it" is unclear.

And yes, "it feels so good" can have a double entendre because, at least in America, anything having to do with sex is frequently made *vague* -- so if your use of "it" is vague, it will tend to attract a sexual meaning.

Answer (score 1):

As you said:

> **I feel (so) good**

involves your personal feeling.

In the case of the other two, it depends on what "it" is. If "it" is causing an indirect feeling, then:

> Hearing that song **makes me feel (so) good.**

is better. But if it is a direct feeling, then you could say:

> **It feels (so) good** the way you are touching me.

Though probably there is some crossover regarding the last two, in that *make* implies a more forceful effect when used.

As for the risk of a double entendre, you need to be careful regarding the context where it is used.