# The foot feels the foot when it feels the ground

Tags: meaning-in-context

> The  foot feels the foot when it feels the ground.

Can you please explain this sentence? I think it has a deep meaning.

Comment: More context please.  What is the source. Please link to the source if possible. Asking about the "deep meaning" may be better on a religious or philosophical stack exchange, if this is a quote from a deep thinker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps it is meant to be about the solipsistic nature of *feeling*.

The foot feels itself when it feels the ground.

The nerve endings of the foot register a tactile sensation which the brain interprets as "the ground underfoot". But all that the body has are its sensations.

Answer (score 3):

As a Buddhist I’d like to make my own connection to the sentence because that’s what this is about connection. Connection with your inner self. BUDDHA uses the foot touching the earth as an analogy. We really only see or feel/sense our foot (read as ourselves) when we feel the ground (read as resistance).

We only truly know ourselves when we meet with resistance, that is when we get a true sense of who we are. When we are tested.

Answer (score 2):

It's a kind of "smartass wordplay". Ordinarily the nerves in your foot won't be sending *any* signals to your brain unless and until there's something to report (such as *heat, abrasion, **pressure**,* etc.). It's not exactly a "deep" meaning - simply a novel way of pointing out that people are only consciously aware of things (even things intimately connected to or part of their own bodies) if they *pay attention to them*.

<sub>(transcribed from comment)</sub>

Comment: Point taken! But I would just say that even as I started to write my "comment that should have been an answer", I knew I was planning to say something along the lines of *you're only aware of those things you're actually paying attention to*. And I also knew that wasn't *quite* right for this context, where it's more a matter of saying *your brain receives no input from sensory nerves unless they're subject to extreme and/or rapidly changing [pressure, temperature, etc.]*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - If you ever want to convert one of these back to your own answer, feel free. Just flag the wiki post, and the mod team will delete it.

Comment: There's an earlier question [“It feels so good” vs. “I feel so good” vs. “It makes me feel so good”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/49144/), but having looked at the answers there I'm not sure any of them explain in a clear-cut way the difference between ***I feel** my toes freezing* and ***My toes** feel freezing*. As a native speaker my first instinct is to say those are just two different ways of saying the same thing, but I don't know how easy it might be for a nns (specifically, OP here) to grasp that - if indeed that's the issue at the root of his comprehension problem.

Answer (score 2):

"The foot feels the foot when it feels the ground" is frequently attributed to the Buddha, but " A bit of searching revealed that it comes from Ernest Wood’s 1971 'Zen Dictionary' (page 91-92) where it’s part of the essay explaining the term 'Naturalness.' The words are Mr. Wood’s, and not the Buddha’s. - https://fakebuddhaquotes.com/the-foot-feels-the-foot-when-it-feels-the-ground/
 "
This aphorism to me says "it is when the foot feels the ground that the foot feels itself."  Presumably, depending on one's philosophical worldview, it means one of the following.  Or perhaps all of them:

1. It is through the Ground of Being that you really know yourself.
2. Know the Self; the ordinary or small self will be then seen truthfully in the right perspective (for what it really is, not according to the separation-based importance that it assigns itself).
3. 1 Corinthians 13:12, "For now we see in a mirror, dimly, but then face to face. Now I know in part, but then I shall know just as I also am known"
4. : 15 My frame was not hidden from you when I was made in the secret place, when I was woven together in the depths of the earth. 16Your eyes saw my unformed body;all the days ordained for me were written in your book before one of them came to be. - Psalm 139:15-16

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the meaning is that you can only understand amd experience real feelings when in contact with others.
At the same time it says that you experience yournplace km the universe as you expose to emotions; meaning you are not aware or them until you come in contact with or experience them.

Answer (score 0):

You feel that you are the right person and you're in the right place when you're doing what you're supposed to be doing. At least that's what I get from it.

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that you can understand the other person's happiness or grief better when you are in the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

To me it sends a perspective of one being well grounded or with out delusions.  Although it’s been found to someone else’s words not Buddha’s.  Let’s look to

Siddhartha Gautama: “Oh lord of my own ego. You are pure illusion. You do not exist. The Earth . . . is my witness.”   So when the foot hits the ground. It should be in so that it shatters illusions and brings clarity with every step